# how to name bools by string values

Tags: c#

So im writing unit tests...

populating an XML on the fly with

```
bool updateFirstName = false;
BuildPersonnelXml(updateFirstName)
```

then passing the XML through the system and creating the user populating all the columns in all the DB table. (Now I want to check all fields are being updated so im writing a separate unit test for each column.) SO now I record the value of a particular column, update the xml with

```
bool updateFirstName = true;
BuildPersonnelXml(updateFirstName)
```

and get the new value from the DB. Comparing the values are diff. If so the update is a success.

However is there anyway to pass in a string value and compare it to a named bool so for example as I write a new test im going to have to go to each previous unit Test and add a new argument FALSE, this will be very time consuming...so is it possible to say

```
string boolToUpdate = "updateFirstName";
BuildPersonnelXml(boolToUpdate)

-----------------------------------------------------
BuildPersonnelXml(boolToUpdate)
{
bool boolToUpdate.ToString() = true;
//so this would be updateFirstName = true;
}
```

Is this possible?

---

**UPDATE**

Thanks to Peter for the help but it isnt resolving my issue so far I have got...

```
Dictionary<string, bool> myVariables = new Dictionary<string, bool>();
myVariables.Add("FirstName", true);
BuildPersonnelXml2(myVariables);
```

Then ....

```
public string BuildPersonnelXml2(Dictionary<string, bool> myVariables)
{
   Tuple<string, bool> myResult = new Tuple(myVariables["bool"], myVariables["FirstName"]);
```

This is firing as 
invalid expression term bool...what am I doing wrong?

### Thank You

**SECOND UPDATE**

Again, Peter, thanks for your help but I dont think you understand my Q...

I cant collect the values by saying

```
new Tuple("FirstName", myVariables["FirstName"]);
```

as the valueName will be different each time...so instead of passing in 3 arguments  with

```
function 1()
bool updateFirstName = true;
BuildPersonnelXml(updateFirstName, false, false)

function 2()
bool updateSurname= true;
BuildPersonnelXml(false, updateSurname, false)

function 3()
bool updateInitials= true;
BuildPersonnelXml(false, false, updateInitials)
```

Im trying to pass the value of the bool and the name of the bool to

```
   BuildPersonnelXml(boolToUpdate)
```

So I can create a bool with the name supplied.
You have shown me how to do

```
function 1()
Dictionary<string, bool> myVariables = new Dictionary<string, bool>();
myVariables.Add("FirstName", true);
BuildPersonnelXml(myVariables)
```

So when I try to do:

```
public string BuildPersonnelXml2(Dictionary<string, bool> myVariables)
{
Tuple<string, bool> myResult = Tuple.Create(myVariables[0], myVariables[1]);
//then I can create the bool with the name supplied and the value
bool myResult[0].ToString() = myResult[1];
//which should be 
bool FirstName = true;
```

Is this possible?

When I try this it is tellling me cannot convert 0 and 1 in `myVariables[0], myVariables[1]` to string...I dont want to conver them i want to use them as index?

am i doing something wrong?
Again thanks for the help

Comment: There are _lots_ of ways, so arguably your question is too broad. But one of the most convenient ways is to use a `Dictionary<string, bool>`, as described in the marked duplicate. So there's that.

Comment: thanks for the reply I have given it a go but to no avail please see UPDATE of OP thanks

Comment: Try `new Tuple("FirstName", myVariables["FirstName"]);` Note also that you can use the indexer syntax (`myVariables["FirstName"]`) to _set_ the value as well as get it, and that doing it that way, you will avoid the exception that `Add()` would throw if you tried to add a key to the dictionary that's already present (e.g. tried to call `myVariables.Add("FirstName", true);` more than once)

Comment: @PeterDuniho thanks for the reply I think you slightly misunderstand my Q please see the second update. thank you

Comment: I understand the question fine. You are not understanding the solution. There is _no way_ to dynamically create an actual local variable with an arbitrary name at run-time. It simply isn't possible; C# requires the compile-time step of declared variables, and that's the only time variables names matter. What you _can_ do is use a data structure like a dictionary to store `bool` values, one value per `string` name. Your attempt to use `int` values with the dictionary makes no sense; the dictionary uses `string` values (the name of the `bool`) and `bool` values (the _value_ of the `bool`)

Answer (score 0):

To use it like this you can use `switch-case` like:

```
swtich(GivenString)
{
     case "updateFirstName":
        updateFirstName = true;
        break;
    .
    .
    .

}
```

Otherwise you should use reflection which I don't recommend in this situation.